# Swap columns with text and photos (html, css and php)

Tags: php, html, css

I am making a website that shows a grid of photos with a little description on the left or right side of the photo. I want that the side that the text appears every time changed, so when you have Photo1 the text is on the left and Photo2 has the text on the right. Now is the case that it need to read out the images, and the text files from a folder, so I used php to get here. Now is my question, how do I get the php right, so it shows what I want it shows?

My code right now (its a little messed up):

```
<li class='row' id='fotos'>
<?php
$dirname1 = "../images/text/";
    $text = scandir($dirname1);
    $dirname = "../images/images/";
    $images = scandir($dirname);
    $ignore = array(".", "..");
    foreach($images as $curimg){
  
        if(!in_array($curimg, $curtext, $ignore)) {

    
    echo "
<div class='image'>
  <img class='img' src='".$dirname.$curimg."'>
</div>
";
        }
    }

?>
</li>
```

And here is the codepen I found, that swaps the divs:

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/VKXPAV)

Someone who knows a way to achieve this or make my code work, thank you already!!

(and thanks for your time)

EDIT:

i want something like this:

```
    <?php
  $dirname = "images-9/images/images/";
  $dirname1 = "images-9/images/text/";
  $text = scandir($dirname1);
  $images = scandir($dirname);
  $ignore = array(".", "..");
  foreach($images as $curimg)($text as $curtext){
          if(!in_array($curimg, $curtext, $ignore)) {
      echo "
      <div class='container'>
        <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-6 order-1'>
            <img src='".$dirname.$curimg."'
          </div>
          <div class='col-6 order-2'>
            <p><iframe src='".$dirname1.$curtext."'
          </div>
        </div>
  
  ";
    }
  }

?>
```

but I know that this code won't work. Is there a way to get this working?

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with the given code? Where does it print anything else than images?

Comment: the php script isn't complete, I don't know how to let php show text and an image. I have tried to edit the foreach() but that turned out to nothing. Maybe do I need to wrote the script another way?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ordering](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#reordering) built into bootstrap, all you need to do is toggle between the 2 class names.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 order-1">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 order-2">
      text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 order-2">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 order-1">
      text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 order-1">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 order-2">
      text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```